how can redirect to absolute url (to subdomain) with react-router-dom
let me explain clearly what I want to do?
 row |            current url             |             redirect to             | component


1    | localhost:3000/panel                | localhost:3000/en/panel             | <Panel />
2    | localhost:3000/login                | localhost:3000/en/panel             | <Panel />
3    | localhost:3000/anyLang/panel        | localhost:3000/sameLang/panel       | <Panel />
4    | localhost:3000/anyLang/login        | localhost:3000/sameLang/panel       | <Panel />

5    | localhost:3000/                     | holding.localhost:3000/en           | <HoldingPage />
6    | localhost:3000/anyLang              | holding.localhost:3000/sameLang     | <HoldingPage />


7    | anySubDomain.localhost:3000/        | sameSubDomain.localhost:3000/en      | <BlogPage />
8    | anySubDomain.localhost:3000/anyLang | sameSubDomain.localhost:3000/sameLang| <BlogPage />

I know part of the solution, although I'm not sure if it's the best solution, please help me complete and optimize the solution.
For the first 4 items, they will all call the panel component, I use this solution
var
    url = window.location.href,
    subdomin = window.location.host.split(".")[0],
    pathName = useLocation().pathname;

  if( pathName.match(/((fa)|(en)|(ar)\/)?((login)|(panel))/) ){
    return(
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/login" />} />
        <Route path="panel" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/panel" />} />
        <Route path="/:lang">
            <Route path="login" element={<Panel />} />
            <Route path="panel" element={<Panel />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    )
  }

But for the next 4 modes, I don't know what to do?

I found the solution, but still the challenge to find better answers.
var
    url = window.location.href,
    pathName = useLocation().pathname;

  if( url.match(/http:\/\/localhost:3000\/((fa|en|ar)\/)?((panel)|(login))/) ){
    return(
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/login" />} />
        <Route path="panel" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/panel" />} />
        <Route path="/:lang">
          <Route path="login" element={<Panel />} />
          <Route path="panel" element={<Panel />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    )
  }
  else if( url.match(/http:\/\/localhost:3000\/((fa|en|ar)\/?)?/) ){
    ['fa','en','ar'].includes(pathName.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''))?
      window.location.replace('http://hol.localhost:3000'+pathName):
      window.location.replace('http://hol.localhost:3000/en/');
  }
  else if(   
url.match(/http:\/\/(archi|vet)\.localhost:3000\/((fa|en|ar)\/?)?/) ){
    if( !pathName.match(/\/(fa|en|ar)\//) )
      return <Navigate to="/en/" />
    else
      return(
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<BlogPages />} />
        </Routes>
      )
  }
  else{
    if( !url.match(/http:\/\/hol\./) )
      window.location.replace('http://hol.localhost:3000'+pathName);
    else if( !pathName.match(/\/(fa|en|ar)\//) )
      return <Navigate to="/en/" />
    else
      return(
        <Routes>
          <Route path="*" element={<HoldingPage />} />
        </Routes>
      )
  }


and this is a shorest answer
if(
    (!subdomain && !/^\/((fa|en|ar)\/)?(panel|login)\/?$/.test(pathName)) ||
    ( subdomain && !['hol','archi','vet'].includes(subdomain) )
  ){
        ['fa','en','ar'].includes(pathName.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''))?
          window.location.replace('http://hol.localhost:3000'+pathName):
          window.location.replace('http://hol.localhost:3000/en/');
  }
  else if( !/^\/(fa|en|ar)(\/.*)?/.test(pathName) ){
    return <Navigate to={`/en${pathName}`}/>
  }
  else{
    return(
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/login" />} />
        <Route path="panel" element={<Navigate replace to="/en/panel" />} />
        <Route path="/:lang">
          <Route path="login" element={<Panel />} />
          <Route path="panel" element={<Panel />} />
          <Route path=""  element={subdomain=='hol'? <HoldingPage /><BlogPages />} />
          <Route path="*" element={subdomain=='hol'? <HoldingPage />: <BlogPages />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    )
  }

